# MSVC 2019 _fxrstor64 and _fxsave64 intrinsics availability

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intrinsics

What are the minimum preprocessor checks I need to make to be sure the compiler is MSVC2019 and that the _fxrstor64 and _fxsave64 intrinsics are available for use?

Comment: If you're doing this in kernel mode there are [better methods to call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-floating-point-or-mmx-in-a-wdm-driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that you have (at least) the MSVC 2019 compiler, you should use the following:

```cpp
#if !defined(_MSC_VER) || (_MSC_VER < 1900)
#error "Not MSVC or MSVC is too old"
#endif
```

For the `_fxrstor64` and `_fxsave64` intrinsics to be available to MSVC, you need to check that the "immintrin.h" header has been included:

```cpp
#ifndef _INCLUDED_IMM
#error "Haven't included immintrin.h"
#endif
```

You also (perhaps obviously) need to be compiling for the x64 architecture:

```cpp
#ifndef _M_X64
#error "Wrong target architetcture!"
#endif
```

You could put all those checks into one test, as follows:

```cpp
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900) && defined(_INCLUDED_IMM) && defined(_M_X64)
    // OK
#else
    #error "Wrong compiler or target architecture, or missing header file."
#endif
```

Note that the `_INCLUDED_IMM` token is *specific* to the MSVC compiler; for example, clang-cl uses `__IMMINTRIN_H`. So, if you also want to enable other, MSVC-compatible compilers, you'll need to add optional checks for each of their own tokens (by looking in the "immintrin.h" header each one uses).

---

As noted in the comments, it would likely be more sensible to explicitly `#include <immintrin.h>` once the other three checks have been made and passed (the include guards in that header would handle any multiple inclusions). So:

```cpp
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900) && defined(_M_X64)
    #include <immintrin.h> // All good!
#else
   // TODO: allow GCC / clang / ICC which also provide _fxsave64 in immintrin.h
    #error "Wrong compiler/version, or not x86-64."
#endif
```

(This also gets round the issue of different implementations using different tokens to signal inclusion of that header file.)

Comment: Seems like you should just `#include <immintrin.h>` inside the `// OK` part (MSVC for x86-64), since it has include guards.  I don't know when it would be useful to actually check `_INCLUDED_IMM` instead of just including it once you've limited things to an x86-64 compiler.

Comment: That's one narrow interpretation of the question phrasing, but probably not what most future readers would want to copy/paste.  It's interesting to mention, sure, but I think we can make it more useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes You convinced me - edited.